# ValueError: not enough values to unpack error in python3 while coding a very basic passwd manager

Tags: python, valueerror

i'm a noob to programming and i keep getting this error while using the *vedere()* function. Sorry if it's a stupid question but i am totally new to python and to this forum. Also sorry if some part of the code is in italian. Btw it's a very basic password manager with some encryption for the passwords, here is the code:

```
import pyfiglet
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

r = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Petrux Passwd Manager", font="slant")
print(r)

'''def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key", "wb") as k:
        k.write(key)'''

def load_key():
    file = open("key.key", "rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key

pwd = input("Inserisci la pswd master:\n")

key = load_key() + pwd.encode()
fernet = Fernet(key)

def aggiungi():
    dominio = input("Dominio:\n")
    email = input("Email o username:\n")
    passwd = input("Password:\n")
    with open("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(dominio + "|" + email + "|" + fernet.encrypt(passwd.encode()).decode() + "\n")
    print("Credenziali aggiunte con successo!")

def vedi():
    with open("5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            dominio, user, passw = data.split("|")
            print("Dominio: ", dominio,"User: ", user, "| Password: ",
                  fernet.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())

while True:
    if pwd == "p3truxx":
        mode = input("Vuoi aggiungere una password o vedere le esistenti?\n(aggiungere/vedere)\n \nOppure scrivi q per uscire\n").lower()
        if mode == "vedere":
            vedi()
        elif mode == "aggiungere":
            aggiungi()
        elif mode == "q":
            quit()
        else:
            print("Input non valido coglione")
    else:
        print("Password sbagliata")
        continue
```

And here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\invic\PycharmProjects\adventure\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    vedi()
  File "C:\Users\invic\PycharmProjects\adventure\main.py", line 35, in vedi
    dominio, user, passw = data.split("|")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: Relevant: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ , [mcve].

Comment: Try printing `data` before you `split` it.  Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: @Samwise yes, it prints the content of the txt file how it is supposed to be

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error. Have you tried deleting the file and retrying?

Comment: That error means the line did not contain `|`.

Comment: @SuperStormer omg thank you so much this was driving me crazy! Do you know why that happened?

Comment: The file had some lines that did not contain `|`, perhaps put there by an earlier version of the code that did not write lines correctly.

Comment: I copied your code and got it working! Just a suggestion: I think instead of using `key.key` you should use `key.txt`. I'm on a MacBook so a `.key` file creates a Keynote file

Comment: Had you `print(repr(line))` right before the fail, you'd see what the problematic line was.

Comment: You mush check your input file, 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99.txt, because the error above means that some line does not contain any | character

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to an user who responded in the comment i tried to create a new file with the same code and worked just fine.
Probably the older .txt file contains some line that doesn't have a "|".